# Discord Bot crashes when a command executed in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am making a Discord Bot. Now I've added command handling. The Bot Starts normal but if I type the command it chrashes with this error code:

```
C:\Users\Matteo\sudo_\sudocanary\index.js:24
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Matteo\sudo_\sudocanary\index.js:24:36)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Matteo\sudo_\sudocanary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Matteo\sudo_\sudocanary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Matteo\sudo_\sudocanary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Matteo\sudo_\sudocanary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Matteo\sudo_\sudocanary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Matteo\sudo_\sudocanary\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Matteo\sudo_\sudocanary\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my Code from the index.js:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    if (command == 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
})



client.login(token);
```

And now the code from the ping.js:

```js
module.exports.execute = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Ping!',
    execute(message) {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    },
};
```

Thanks! (I am using discord.js v12)

Comment: `module.exports` instead of `module.exports.execute`. Also, you're not adding anything to the `client.commands` Collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your index.js, you need to add your commands to your `client.commands` in order to actually use them. You've also used `module.exports.execute` in your ping.js, whereas you should  be using just `module.exports` (the `execute()` method is already defined within your `module.exports`, as the method `execute(message)`).

Here are the fixes in your code.

index.js:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

ping.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Ping!',
    execute(message) {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    },
};
```

Please look more closely at the examples of the command handler you are attempting to use, as they show the proper way to do this and explain what each part of the command handler does. I would advise going through [the discordjs.guide command handler examples](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files) and learning how everything works.